# java.sql.SQLException: No data read- jdbcTemplete

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, data-access

Trying to run the query using `jdbcTemplete` on oracle database where `M_DB` is the schema name and `M_USER_DB` is user for `M_DB` schema. `M_USER_DB` has certain tables on which I am trying to execute some queries like in springboot project

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM M_USER_DB.C_USER_INFO", new ResultSetExtractor<HashMap<String, String>>()
```

However, while running the program its throwing below error:

```
 No data read; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No data read
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
```

In the `application.properties` the `database/datasource` connection are for my primary Schema `M_DB` (not user `M_USER_DB` ). From SqlDeveloper, I can connect to `M_DB` and run the query like

```
select * from M_USER_DB.C_USER_INFO
```

without connecting to `M_USER_INFO`. I believe I need not to create primary and secondary jdbcTemplete here.

Any suggestion what could be the reason or anything I am missing? Thanks for help in advance.